# Change the look and feel of the user registration form

Tags: 8, theming

What I've done so far is that I have copied the contents of the file `page.html.twig` into a newly created file `page--user--register.html.twig`.

But I don't know how to change the look and feel of the registration form.

Comment: Hey Jack, we love to help you, but it's absolutely unclear what you asking. I naively would answer this question: With CSS. But what exactly do you mean by "look and feel"?

Comment: hi @leymannx i want to change the layout of the registration form. I tried lot of websites but there is no precise way,

Answer (score 1):

1)Alter theme suggestion in your-theme.theme file.

```
function hook_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

if ($hook == 'form' & !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {
 $suggestions[] = 'form__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']  ['#id']);
}
}
```

2)Create **form--user-register-form.html.twig** in your themes template folder and make changes according to your requirement.

```
 <div id="login" class="ptb ptb-xs-60 page-signin">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main-body">
      <div class="body-inner">
        <div class="card bg-white">
          <div class="card-content">
            <section class="logo text-center">
              <h2>Register</h2>
            </section>
            <form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="ui-input-group">
                    <label>Your username</label>
                    {{ element.account.name }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="ui-input-group">


                    <label>Your email</label>
                   {{ element.account.mail }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="ui-input-group">

                    <label>Your password </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="ui-input-group">

                    <label>Please confirm your password </label>
                    {{ element.account.pass }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <div class="form-group checkbox-field">
                  <label for="check_box" class="text-small">
                    <input id="check_box" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty22 custom-check"></span>{{ element.terms_of_use }}
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
             {{ element.form_build_id }} {# required #}
             {{ element.form_id }} {# required #}
          <div class="card-action no-border text-right"> <a href="#/page/signin">Login</a><a href="#/" class="color-primary">{{ element.actions.submit }}</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the page template if you only want to change to login form. Take a look at the rendered output. Maybe you can achieve your requirements by simple CSS changes in your theme.

If not, go for the templates of form, form-element, input, container.

Or, if you have a custom module, override the login form of the user module.